# Customise UIDate picker

Tags: swift

I was trying to do little bit of customisation on date picker. I realise that there are limited customisation for it.

As in the Image I shared I managed to make the tex colour to white with this code below

```
   datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
```

Now My Problem is that as seen the picture today is in black colour. Is there anyway to make it white line other dates.[reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPwrj.png)

Answer (score 0):

Tested on iOS 14.5 :

```
if #available(iOS 13.4, *) {
      datePicker.preferredDatePickerStyle = .wheels
        datePicker.setValue(UIColor.white, forKeyPath: "textColor")
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
        datePicker.datePickerMode = .dateAndTime
}
```

Comment: I tried this and all the text are white. But "Today" was replaced by today's date.

Comment: @SabazShereef _setHighlightColor has no impact on the textColor, you can only disable highlightsToday in this case.

Comment: Thanks @RTGamer Do you recomend me to go for some way to achieve it?

Comment: @SabazShereef updated answer you can check now.